# No Highlight syntax in Specflow Feature Files on Visual Studio for Mac (AKA Xamarin)

Tags: macos, xamarin, specflow, xamarin.uitest

There has been a new issue with Feature files on VS as of March 2020 with the new updates done to VS. There seems to be an issue where the Feature file does not have their highlighted text as they did before the update. Today 04/12/2020 I tried to update to the latest VS for mac updates and Xcode with the same issue. My guess is that the VS for mac extension know as straight-eight/SpecFlow-VS-Mac-Integration needs to be updated to the latest updates but that is a guess, as I posted a question on there git hub with no response that can be found here: https://github.com/straighteight/SpecFlow-VS-Mac-Integration/issues/18
My question is, is there anyone out there that has the latest VS for mac updates as of 04/12/2020 that does not have this issue and if you do not have the issue how did you fix it?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Instead of posting here, you should probably use the Report Feedback feature in Visual Studio for Mac.

Comment: I was not sure if this is a VS for mac issue or it has to do with the people that made the extension. That is why I am posting it here, but thank you for the heads up, ill use the feedback feature and see where that gets me.

Comment: Have you tried updating or reinstalling the extension?

Comment: I have, and the same issue happened when doing that, also there does not seem to be an update for the extension.

Comment: Someone posted a comment on your GitHub issue: https://github.com/straighteight/SpecFlow-VS-Mac-Integration/issues/18#issuecomment-614072030

Comment: @Cheesebaron I did use the report feedback button and opened a ticket with Microsoft found here https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/989950/no-highlight-syntax-in-specflow-feature-files-on-v.html#reply-form

based off what they are stating I am at the mercy of the extension developer to fix the issue and I hope there is something they do soon.

Comment: @GregBurghardt yes that is the Microsoft guy that I posted a ticket too, that is his fix for the issue of the extension not working with the latest updates.

Comment: I created a PR to fix that issue in the SpecFlow Github, all they need to do is merge it and release a new version!

Comment: as of 09-02-2020  there is still no highlighting in feature files anymore. Is this just an issue with VS for mac and is there anything I can do to fix this? I can't imagine that I am one of the few people that use spec flow on mac?.